# How do i get the value for the key of an object in a firestore database iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
let db = Firestore.firestore()
let query = db.collection("users").whereField("email", isEqualTo: email).value(forKey: "email")
```

This is my code. I want to retrieve from a firestore database an object. Then i want to retrieve the value for a key. The issue is that it crashes with the following code.

Any fix or something like that?

Comment: The fix is contained in the documentation - there is more code needed to retrieve data for your query. See [Execute a query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#execute_a_query)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not reading anything from Firestore yet:

```
let query = db.collection("users").whereField("email", isEqualTo: email).value(forKey: "email")
```

This merely defines a query that (when executed) will find documents in the `users` collection. In fact, I think you'll want to leave it at:

```
let query = db.collection("users").whereField("email", isEqualTo: email)
```

Now you need to [get data once](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_multiple_documents_from_a_collection), or [listen for realtime updates](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen). The first one is simplest:

```
query.getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
    if let err = err {
        print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
    } else {
        for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
            print("\(document.documentID) => \(document.data())")
        }
    }
}
```

The `document.data()` in here is a dictionary, so you can get the value of any field from that through the dictionary, or with `document.get("field")`.